# Grafana не видит InfluxDB

Tags: база-данных, grafana, influxdb, chronograf

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. Когда я создаю соединение в графане к бд инфлюкса, выходит ошибка:
InfluxDB Error: Bad Gateway
В хронографе я вижу бд инфлюска. Но порт 8086 у меня не открывается, но через командную строку все работает как и через python. В чем может быть проблема? на что стоит обратить внимание?
Спасибо за любые советы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы указали как я понял localhost в поле хоста на графане, попробуйте указать туда айпи адрес своей машины. У меня была такая же проблема с Prometheus.

Comment: Получилось! спасибо!